# How to get a location UIImageView. There are many UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift4

I am creating multiple `UIImageView`s in code, and want to move and delete any `UIImageView` I chose. Right now, I can only move the last `UIImageView` that was created using `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

I want to able to choose to move or delete any `UIImageView` that I created (using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` or `UITapGestureRecognizer`), not just the last one.

---

Here's some code that I have been using:

```
import UIKit

var pointX: CGFloat = 0.0
var pointY: CGFloat = 0.0
var w: CGFloat = 50
var h: CGFloat = 50
var flag: Int = 0

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tapG: UITapGestureRecognizer!
    @IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view_safe: UIView!
    var boxViewArray: Array<UIImageView> = []
    var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    var drag = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func tapGesture_action(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let boxImage: UIImage
        let point = sender.location(in: view_safe)

        pointX = point.x
        pointY = point.y

        //四角形のイメージを生成
        boxImage = makeBoxImage(x: pointX-(w/2), y: pointY-(h/2), width: w, height: h)

        var tmp: UIImageView = UIImageView()
        tmp = UIImageView(image: boxImage)
        tmp.tag = flag
        flag += 1

        tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()

        drag = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panView(sender:)))
        tmp.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        tmp.addGestureRecognizer(drag)

        boxViewArray.append(tmp)

        self.ImageView.addSubview(boxViewArray.last!)
        //self.ImageView.bringSubview(toFront: boxViewArray.last!)
    }

    func makeBoxImage(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width w: CGFloat, height h: CGFloat) -> UIImage{
        print("makeBoxImage 開始")
        //イメージ処理の開始
        let size = CGSize(width: ImageView.frame.width, height: ImageView.frame.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 1.0)
        //コンテキスト
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        //サイズを決める
        let drawRect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)
        //パスを作る
        let drawPath = UIBezierPath(rect: drawRect)
        //塗り色
        context?.setFillColor(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        //パスを塗る
        drawPath.fill()
        //線の色
        context?.setStrokeColor(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        //パスを描く
        drawPath.stroke()
        //イメージコンテキストからUIImageを作る
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        //イメージ処理の終了
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image!
    }

    @objc func panView(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

        //let tagNo = sender.view?.tag
        //print(tagNo)
        //移動量を取得
        let move: CGPoint = sender.translation(in:self.view)
        //ドラッグした部品の座標に移動量を加算
        sender.view!.center.x += move.x
        sender.view!.center.y += move.y
        //移動量を0に
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
    }

    @objc func delete_tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("delete")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print(#function)
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: view_safe)
            print(location)

        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: view_safe)
        let thePoint: CGPoint = location
        let hitView: UIView = UIView()

        hitView.hitTest(thePoint, with: event)
        //NSLog("Hit Test : tag = %ld", hitView.tag)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()}
}
```

Comment: Confusing code and question, but I'll wager that you are trying to attach a **single** gesture to **multiple** views. That's doesn't work. If you wish to attach a *common* function (say a delete function) to *multiple* views (be they `UIImageViews` or `UILabels` or basically any `UIView` or subclass), you need to (1) create a separate gesture for each view, (2) point it's action to the common function, and (3) attach that *separate* gesture to the *individual* view.

Comment: is collectionView an option? if not, I suggest to have a custom class that would have a callback when you touch it and perform the needed operation there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just will help you with the logic.

You need a list for your image view. On every tap you will check what imageview tapped by checking every imageview location. *dont check your tap on image view, check your tap on view controller.

if you want move the object by pan, your code is right if you apply that to the imageview after u know which imageview will moved.

hope will help you.

*i had created this logic before, but its a little tricky

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to remove the ImageView from the superview.

```
@objc func delete_tapped(_ sender: Any){
    let image = sender as! UIImageView
    image.removeFromSuperview()
    print("delete")
}
```